# Can not convert json string to object

Tags: java, json, servlets, org.json

I'm constructiong a JSONObject in my javascript and then sending it as a string to my servlet using this code:

```
insertDtls = function() {
                    var jsonObj = [];
                    jsonObj.push({location: this.location()});
                    jsonObj.push({value: this.value()});
                    jsonObj.push({coverage: this.coverage()});
                    jsonObj.push({validPeriod: this.collateralValidPer()});
                    jsonObj.push({description: this.description()});

                    var b = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
                    console.log(b.toString());

                     $.ajax({
                             url:"/HDSWFHub/AppProxy",
                             type: 'GET',
                             data: $.extend({WrJOB: "insertDtls", mainData: b}, tJS.getCommonPostData()),
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function(responseText, status, xhr){
                                               updateViewModel(responseText);
                                           },
                             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
                                               tJS.manageError(jqXHR);
                                           }
                 });
 },
```

The string looks like:
`[{"location":"Boston"},{"value":"5"},{"coverage":"15"},{"validPeriod":"08/05/2013"},{"description":"test description"}]` and the servlet receives it without a problem.

Then I'm getting this in my servlet:

```
String step = request.getParameter("mainData");

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            System.out.println(step);
            try {
                obj.put("viewModel", "index");
                obj.put("WrSESSIONTICKET", sessionTicket);
                response.getWriter().print(obj.toString());
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                logException(request, response, e, true);
            }
```

I'm trying to convert the JSON string back to object in the servlet in order to be able to loop trough the items, or to get the needed one. The library I'm using is `org.json`

I have tired:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(step);
```

Without any success. Just got this error:
`Unhandled exception type JSONException`
 I don't know what is happening. Maybe I'm too tired already. I'm sure that I'm missing something really small, but I'm unable to spot it.

I know that it has been asked hundreds of times. I know that I will get tons of downvotes, but I was unable to find an answer for my issue.

Comment: you said you tried `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(step);` but I don't see it in the code!

Comment: Because it is not working. :) This is teh error: `Unhandled exception type JSONException`

Comment: Print out the variable `step` in the servlet and see if it is a correct JSON string. Please post it so we can all review it ;)

Comment: here it is: `[{"location":"Boston"},{"value":"5"},{"coverage":"15"},{"validPeriod":"08/05/2013"},{"description":"test description"}]`

Comment: I see. This is a json array. A json object starts with `{` and ends with `}`. Thus, this will work: `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(step);`

Comment: Here is what I got again: `Unhandled exception type JSONException` :(

Comment: hmmmm....which library are you using?

Comment: `org.json` I'm also wondering why I can not get it working.

Comment: In fact, i noticed something in your string... `2013` in particular the zero and one are not ascii characters...This might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the string you posted in your comment and it works fine. Here is the full code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class jsonArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "[{\"location\":\"Boston\"},{\"value\":\"5\"},{\"coverage\":\"15\"},{\"validPeriod\":\"08/05/2013\"},{\"description\":\"test description\"}]";

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);
            System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. I am using org.json-20120521.jar library

Comment: great, but you have escaped something. I'm getting the string from the javascript with the help of ajax.

Comment: Add your json code inside `try {...} catch (JSONException e) {... }`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I can't belive how stucked my brain was. Thanks for helping me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here your json String is converted to JSONObject .

In your case its not happening because **`[]` brackets denotes Array**. so first it is Array and then **`{}` JSONObject** in case of your String.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    static String str = "[{\"location\":\"Boston\"},{\"value\":\"5\"},{\"coverage\":\"15\"},{\"validPeriod\":\"08/05/2013\"},{\"description\":\"test description\"}]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(str);
        System.out.println("JSON ARRAY IS : ");
        System.out.println(jsonArr.toString());
            for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(i+" JSON OBJECT IS : ");
                System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());

            }
    } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
JSON ARRAY IS : 
[{"location":"Boston"},{"value":"5"},{"coverage":"15"},{"validPeriod":"08/05/2013"},{"description":"test description"}]

0 JSON OBJECT IS : 
{"location":"Boston"}

1 JSON OBJECT IS : 
{"value":"5"}

2 JSON OBJECT IS : 
{"coverage":"15"}

3 JSON OBJECT IS : 
{"validPeriod":"08/05/2013"}

4 JSON OBJECT IS : 
{"description":"test description"}
```